# Request to vote in community moderator election keeps reappearing

Tags: bug, top-bar, global-inbox

Every couple days I have a "new" alert in my inbox, if I go looking at it I find some messages from February, click it away and then the recent messages appear (no new ones though). The screenshot below is taken on Area51, it also regularly happens on Arqade.

I just noticed that I *did* have a *real* new alert, that then got "read" because I looked at the old ones.

[image]

Comment: @DroidDev It is indeed. Did not notice that question.

Comment: Usually, I don't remember the questions, but that is asked by a moderator and employee. Still no action is taken.

Comment: Aha! just noticed something that can help in reproducing. Adding into the question.

Comment: I think it would be better if you edit the other question. The one which I linked to your question.

Comment: I'll edit both!